# Enumerating all fields from a GraphQL query

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-js, apollo-server, graphql-tools

Given a GraphQL schema and resolvers for [Apollo Server](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/), and a GraphQL query, is there a way to create a collection of all requested fields (in an Object or a Map) in the resolver function?

For a simple query, it's easy to recreate this collection from the `info` argument of the resolver.

Given a schema:

```
type User {
  id: Int!
  username: String!
  roles: [Role!]!
}

type Role {
  id: Int!
  name: String!
  description: String
}

schema {
  query: Query
}

type Query {
  getUser(id: Int!): User!
}
```

and a resolver:

```
Query: {
  getUser: (root, args, context, info) => {
    console.log(infoParser(info))

    return db.Users.findOne({ id: args.id })
  }
}
```

with a simple recursive `infoParser` function like this:

```
function infoParser (info) {
  const fields = {}

  info.fieldNodes.forEach(node => {
    parseSelectionSet(node.selectionSet.selections, fields)
  })

  return fields
}

function parseSelectionSet (selections, fields) {
  selections.forEach(selection => {
    const name = selection.name.value

    fields[name] = selection.selectionSet
      ? parseSelectionSet(selection.selectionSet.selections, {})
      : true
  })

  return fields
}
```

The following query results in this log:

```
{
  getUser(id: 1) {
    id
    username
    roles {
      name
    }
  }
}

=> { id: true, username: true, roles: { name: true } }
```

Things get pretty ugly pretty soon, for example when you use fragments in the query:

```
fragment UserInfo on User {
  id
  username
  roles {
    name
  }
}

{
  getUser(id: 1) {
    ...UserInfo
    username
    roles {
      description
    }
  }
}
```

GraphQL engine correctly ignores duplicates, (deeply) merges etc. queried fields on execution, but it is not reflected in the `info` argument. When you add [unions](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-guide/blob/master/source/queries.md#fragments-for-unions) and [inline fragments](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-guide/blob/master/source/queries.md#inline-fragments) it just gets hairier.

Is there a way to construct a collection of all fields requested in a query, taking in account advanced querying capabilities of GraphQL?

Info about the `info` argument can be found [on the Apollo docs site](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/resolvers.html) and in the [graphql-js Github repo](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/c82ff68f52722c20f10da69c9e50a030a1f218ae/src/type/definition.js#L489-L500).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it has been a while but in case anyone ends up here, there is an npm package called [graphql-list-fields](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-list-fields) by [Jake Pusareti](https://github.com/jakepusateri) that does this. It handles fragments and skip and include directives.
you can also check the code [here](https://github.com/jakepusateri/graphql-list-fields/blob/master/index.js).